# Monitor for XPS 15

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 15, and I want to buy a monitor so that I can have two monitors to work with.

However, I see that there is an HDMI output which I cannot use with Ubuntu (https://askubuntu.com/questions/61144/how-do-i-get-hdmi-output-working-on-a-dell-xps-15-l502x), and my alternative is the Minidisplay Port. I am confused because mainly all monitors have VGA.  What would be a good solution that would give me a good image quality? Which kind of monitor/cable I am looking for?

Comment: Obviously it would work with monitors that have a MiniDP input, but according to the Wikipedia article on [Mini DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort), "With a suitable adapter, Mini DisplayPort may be used to drive displays with a VGA, DVI or HDMI interface." HDMI would probably be the best and Amazon sells [things](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2/187-7687078-2742908?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=MiniDisplay%20Port%20to%20HDMI%20Adapter) like that.

Comment: I always get my adapters from NewEgg. @martineau, MiniDP also has an adapter for full size display port. Think of a DisplayPort/MiniDisplayPort as a wild card; with an adapter it can be VGA, DVI, HDMI or DP.

Comment: @Nobita, Keep in mind that the link that you posted was dated back in 2011. The latest version of Ubuntu may not have these issues. I would suggest getting a friend to let you test on their monitor to see if the HDMI works. Or try it out with your TV (if it supports HDMI).

Comment: @kobaltz: I wasn't endorsing Amazon -- just providing examples. NewEgg would have worked just as well.

Comment: @kobaltz I have already tried that, and yes, there is no signal from HDMI. So, my question would be. Should I buy an adaptor from MiniDV to VGA? I have read the quality is really bad, and that is basically my concern.

Comment: @Nobita The quality is not bad. I typically go with either the Apple ones (i like their style) or Startech. If the adaptor works then the quality will be as good as it can be. You must be thinking about USB2-VGA Adaptors. Those are really bad.

Comment: @kobaltz so, I should just buy a MiniDisplay to VGA and I would be good to go, right? If you want to do an answer, I will accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of a DisplayPort/MiniDisplayPort as a wild card; with an adapter it can be VGA, DVI, HDMI or DP. The quality of the adapter can affect the signal, but for the most part, just pick one that has good reviews. You should not see any issues with using the MiniDisplayPort to VGA adapter.